# jQuery regex match help (optional condition)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got something like that:

```
[@parameter='value']
```

and

```
[@parameter]
```

and I need regexp to parse both cases,
in first returns parameter & value in the second only parameter

Now, I've got something like that

```
"[@short-name='shorty']".match(/\[\@(.*)\=\'(.*)\'\]/)
```

which returns

```
["[@short-name='shorty']", "short-name", "shorty"]
```

its great but only in first case, please help

**EDIT:**

I just figured that probably two matches could be replaced by one so if it's possible, a little extension of current solution will be great.

match something like:

```
PARENT//CHILD[@parameter='value']
```

or

```
PARENT//CHILD[@parameter]
```

or

```
PARENT//CHILD
```

should returns

```
[ parent, child, parameter, value ]

[ parent, child, parameter ]

[ parent, child ]
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 2:**

Allright it's easy

```
/([A-Z]+)\/\/([A-Z]+)(\[@([^=\]]*)(?:='(.*)'])?)?/
```

if it's possible to do it easier, please show me how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your general case:

```
/\[@([^=\]]*)(?:='(.*)'])?/
```

I removed a lot of the unnecessary escaping you were doing.  The *value* is in parentheses (not captured because of `?:`) and then made optional.  The `\[@.*` has to be changed to `\[@[^=\]]` so that it will only try to capture up to the equals or the close brace (either of which may be there).

You can also update this to correctly match quotes, or even omit them

```
/\[@([^=\]]*)(?:=(['"]?)(.*)\2])?/
```

EDIT: You can also match multiple values per line using a similar expression; just add `.*?` for the capture of the value.

```
"[@short-name='shorty'] [@long-name=\"longy\"] [@longest]".replace(
    /\[@([^=\]]*)(?:=(['"]?)(.*?)\2])?/g,
function () { console.log(arguments[1], arguments[3]); })
```

This will yield `"short-name, shorty", "long-name longy", "longest undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

Let the second part be optional. 
Put some spaces to best view.

```
"[@short-name]".match(/\[\@(.*)   (\=\'(.*)\')?    \]/)
```

Wrapping the code with parentheses and adding a `?` will do the trick.
http://metahtml.sourceforge.net/documentation/regex/regex_3.mhtml#SEC14

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3p403Y152d0q
Please test before you answer...in first case it doesn't work